# creating symbolic link and setting environment variables

Tags: symbolic-link, paths

I've compiled Gamit/Globk software from the source codes. The installation directory's path "/home/sorbilene/GAMIT".

I need to create links and set environment variables to run the software without problem. I'm a new user for ubuntu so I don't get them exactly. The below are the necessary links and setting variables.

1-) Making required ~/gg link to newly installed software:

```
ln -s -f /home/sorbilene/GAMIT ~/gg
```

2-)Don't forget to set your : path to include

```
 /home/sorbilene/GAMIT/gamit/bin and /home/sorbilene/GAMIT/kf/bin 

                     : HELP_DIR environment variable in you shell profile
                       (in .cshrc/.tcshrc add: setenv HELP_DIR /home/sorbilene/GAMIT/help/)
                     : INSTITUTE evnironment variable in your shell profile
                       (in your .cshrc/.tcshrc add: setenv INSTITUTE where_i_work)
                       where_i_work is a 3 character identifier for your solutions
```

Could anyone explain, what they're stand for and how can I set these paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your terminal and type:

```
cd ~

gksu gedit .bashrc
```

and out these lines in the file:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/gamit/gamit/bin

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/gamit/kf/bin

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/gamit/com

export HELP_DIR=/usr/local/gamit/help/

export INSTITUTE=UGM
```

You'll need to provide the path according to your installation.

Refer [here](https://laksonoade.wordpress.com/2012/10/24/install-gamit-on-ubuntu/).

Answer (score 1):

> Making required ~/gg link to newly installed software:

you have to run

```
ln -s /home/sorbilene/GAMIT/bin/the-executable(binary-command) ~/gg
```

example: if i have a file in my home called a.txt and want to make  a link on desktop then run the command `ln -s ~/a.txt ~/Desktop`

If i want to rename the link to a new name suppose b.txt `ln -s ~/a.txt ~/Desktop/b.txt`

> How to set PATH

To set PATH environment. Add the path of the binaries to the PATH.

```
PATH=$PATH:/home/sorbilene/GAMIT/bin
```

Now to make this persistent to this user you have to add to `.bashrc`

```
gedit .bashrc
```

and then add this line

```
PATH=$PATH:/home/sorbilene/GAMIT/bin
```

save and close then run the command

```
source .bashrc
```